# How can I get 'after:now' in Laravel 4's Validator class to respond correctly to a UK date?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on an application in Laravel 4 that needs users to input UK format dates (dd/mm/yyyy). At present the Laravel's `Validator` class is validating the format with no problem. However, some of the dates supplied also need to be in the future or need to be compared to each other. At present `after:` seems to be evaluating against US date format which isn't much help.

Is there any way that I can get `Validator` to recognise my date format or is it a case of me having to validate the input format first, convert the date and then validate it again to check that it's in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: You can extend the Validate class and add your own validate{Method} to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laravel doc says:

> The field under validation must be a valid date according to the
> strtotime PHP function.

The strtotime php doc states that this function parse in US format.
But a additionnal note states:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So I'll reccommend you tu force the use of - instead of / (with a validation or with a str_replace filter) or create a custom validator that uses DateTime::createFromFormat() as suggested in the php doc.

Maybe I'll do a push request to replace strtotime to DateTime::createFromFormat() in the default Validator if it is really more reliable (need to investigate the two first)

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like switching to the - separator is the simplest way to go.